# How to call node server to fetch data in web application using Facebook Flux?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I am new to react and flux. I am trying to build a simple application using the flux architecture and I got stuck that how can I fetch the data from the from node server. I have searched about that and every link that I have found, just show that I have to use ajax to fetch the data from the server, But I don't want to do that.

As my current app was build on Angular and node js and I can easily  call the server to fetch data through `$http` services. But I didn't find that kind of thing in react or flux, even there is no routing concept available in react document ion , We need use third party component for routing.

So my question that is there any way so that I can fetch my data from server without using ajax and for routing don't have to use third party component. Please help me to figure it out. here's are the some of the link that I have found :

http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

http://www.code-experience.com/async-requests-with-react-js-and-flux-revisited/

http://madebymany.com/blog/beyond-the-to-do-app-writing-complex-applications-using-flux-react-js

Answer (score 1):

React bills itself as the View in MVC and leaves it up to you to handle the Model and Controller.  The idea is that it is open enough to use whatever library you want for ajax and routing.  As far as routing goes, [React Router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) is generally the go-to solution that I've seen.  For ajax/data fetching, Facebook is working to open source their solution called [Relay](https://gist.github.com/wincent/598fa75e22bdfa44cf47) but for now, you can use jQuery, vanilla js or any 3rd party javascript plugin that fetches data.

React is NOT meant to replace Ember/Angular/WhateverJS, at least not entirely.  It is ONLY responsible for the view portion of your application.  It's only purpose is to draw your views then redraw them intelligently when you change data.  That means you'll have to take care of the routing and data fetching.  Additionally, Flux is just a design pattern, it's not a library you require and use.

Comment: Yes I read about the relay but it's in initials state and they are still working on it. But still my question remains same as if i have to use any third party api to fetch the data then why would i use react or flux.

Comment: @Toretto I updated my answer in at attempt to clarify

Answer (score 1):

[Superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) is a nice alternative to ajax. It's not all that different from using $http in angular.

```
var request = require('superagent');

request
  .post('/api/pet')
  .send({ name: 'Manny', species: 'cat' })
  .set('X-API-Key', 'foobar')
  .set('Accept', 'application/json')
  .end(function(error, res){

  });
```

It's a good idea to make a module that collects all these in one place, which you can `require` wherever you need to make the actual API call.

As for routing, if you don't want to use a third party library like ReactRouter, I think it should be possible to roll your own using switch/case statements with `window.location` and just render different components depending on the current url. You'd also have to set the valid routes on the server to point to the same entry point for your app, or use a catch-all route.

It may seem like React/Flux are 'incomplete' since they're lacking built-in ways to do these things, but they do a good job of solving the specific problems that they were designed for. That's a very good reason to use them, even if it means combining them with other tools to get the functionality you want.

Answer (score 0):

The Flux is an architectural concept. Particular implementations may include helpers for fetching data from a server but usually they don't because this isn't a problem Flux solves and the way your app communicates with a server can differ depending on a particular goal.

You can fetch you data using any way (and library) you like but there is no built in solution.

Talking about the router. Again, this isn't a problem Flux solves. Some apps need routing, others don't. There is no reason to include it in some of the implementations.

There is no built in solution. The most widely used routing library for React is:
https://github.com/rackt/react-router

I strongly recommend to start from the basics and thoroughly go through the overview:
http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html